# Incorrect Product Code in OpenFDA Recalls Database

Tags: openfda

I noticed that when I look at product recall "Z-1973-2012" in the OpenFDA Recalls database, it returns with a result containing Product Code "CGA".
However the same recall number on FDA's [Recall Search](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfRES/res.cfm) site returns an [entry](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfRES/res.cfm?id=110215) with Product Code "CHL".
Are such issues known with the Product Codes in the OpenFDA Recalls database?

Answer (score 0):

The data openFDA receives internally for this dataset does have `CGA`. We will investigate internally and report back with findings.

Thank you for bringing this to our attention.

Comment: Any update Denis?

Comment: This is now fixed in openFDA.

Comment: Thanks Denis.  I'm curious... do you know the cause of the original error and what was required to resolve it?

Comment: It was just a data entry error on the FDA side

Comment: Ah humans... often the strongest part of a system, but sometimes the weakest link! ;)